# Accessing Azure Cloud Service PaaS Instances via PowerShell remoting

Tags: powershell, azure, rdp, powershell-remoting, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure Web Role with 2 Instances (NB the PaaS Roles, ***not Azure Virtual Machines**). I can connect to them via Remote Desktop, but I don't know how to do Remoting in Powershell (PowerShell Remoting), because unlike with a Azure Virtual Machine Cloud Service, there is no way to define an Endpoint and Port for each instance as there are not separate addresses for each Worker Role.

How can I connect to an individual PaaS Worker Role Instance via Powershell Remoting ? IOW how can I use:

```
Enter-PSSession –ComputerName PC1 –Credential User
```

against a Cloud Service Worker Role (PaaS) Instance?

Comment: Check the endpoints for the correct port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PowerShell Remoting (not to be confused with RDP) looks to be perfectly possible for Azure VMs:

> PowerShell Remoting needs the correct network configuration to allow
>   for remote connectivity. Since we will be accessing the VM over the
>   web we are required to use HTTPS to secure the communication channel.
>   Skipping over the details of Windows Remote Management which is used
>   by PowerShell Remoting, I will just say the default HTTPS port is
>   5986.
>
> To allow connectivity to the VM this endpoint must be added to the
>   ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<endpoints>
    <inputendpoint localport="5986" port="5986" protocol="tcp" name="WinRM" /> 
</endpoints>
```

> With the proper port open it is just a matter of enabling PowerShell
>   Remoting. Two issues need to be resolved before enabling it.
>
> The first is using the correct user account to setup Remoting. You
>   must use the account previously created to run the script to setup
>   Remoting[1]. With these commands the user you previously created will
>   execute the script e:\approot\StartRemotingListener.ps1:

```
schtasks /CREATE /TN "StartRemotingListener" /SC ONCE /SD 01/01/2020 /ST 00:00:00 
               /RL HIGHEST /RU <username> /RP <password> 
               /TR "powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted 
                               -Command e:\approot\StartRemotingListener.ps1 -Force" /F
schtasks /RUN /TN "StartRemotingListener"
```

> The second issue is configuring the certificate needed for the HTTPS
>   connection. Acquiring a certificate might not be a problem for a
>   production environment. You might already have one for your service
>   and could reuse it. It can be a problem if your service doesn’t
>   require a certificate for normal operation or for non-production
>   environments.

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariok/archive/2011/08/08/command-line-access-to-azure-vms-powershell-remoting.aspx

Comment: I added the endpoint=5986 to ServiceDefinition.csdef and I did new deployment in Azure. But it still doesn't work. As it is written in article you sent for me : "This method will only allow connections to services with a single instance" , while I have two instances.  The point is I can easily connect to VM by Powershell Remoting, but I can not do the same for and instance of Cloud Service. When I edit rdp files for Connecting to VM and instance, I see that Instance has somethings more like the following which I don't know how to specify it in Powershell Remoting:

Comment: "full address:s: MyService.cloudapp.net username:s:Username **LoadBalanceInfo:s:Cookie: mstshash=WorkerRole1#WorkerRole1_IN_0**"

Answer (score -2):

Using Azure management portal you can download the RDP files used to connect. Edit those files you should have all the details needed for connecting (end points and ports).

btw, Azure uses port forwarding for specific instance access.

Comment: Thanks, but in the file is written : 

full address:s: MyService.cloudapp.net
username:s:Username
LoadBalanceInfo:s:Cookie: mstshash=WorkerRole1#WorkerRole1_IN_0  

So, How should I use the "mstshash"  in the Enter-PSSession command ?

Comment: Do you know how to do it in Powershell Remoting, ? how can I specify the following in the powershell :  "full address:s: MyService.cloudapp.net username:s:Username **LoadBalanceInfo:s:Cookie: mstshash=WorkerRole1#WorkerRole1_IN_0**"

Comment: Why not run mstsc.exe with the rdp file as a parameter??